# php - does each html form in a page require a different php file for each?

Tags: php, html

When processing a form server side, we need make sure the HTML form has its method and action set like the following:

```
<form action="filename.php" method="post">
....
</form>
```

I understand that we can use jquery/javascript to handle form submit differently (e.g. executing functions in more than one .php files) but does this mean that if I have 3 forms on a page - let's say a contact form, a subscription form, and a user lookup / search form - then I need 3 .php files for each?

Comment: it depends on you, but would be better to have each file that process each form for readability incase someone else can work on the site

Comment: No, there is no such requirement. Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve, or an issue you are facing with your code?

Comment: you can pass parameter for that and check on server side

Comment: No, you don't need a php file for each form, you can add a hidden field in each of the forms that identifies each form on the single php page.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile that's what I thought, but when considering scalability, a site that incorporates lots of forms would mean lots of php files and that would be inefficient right?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid the question is exactly that in the last sentence: do I need to have separate php files for each form action that does different things? There's no such requirement but that is why I'm wondering if there's an alternative.

Comment: @AjayDeepakKumar and Epodax, thanks! I'm just starting to learn php form handling and what you guys said makes sense I'm just not too sure what are the alternatives are (other than javascript/jquery) and how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need multiple files you can do it something like below:

```
<form name="form1" action="filename.php" method="post">
....
<input type="submit" name="form1-submit" value="form1" />
</form>

<form name="form2" action="filename.php" method="post">
....
<input type="submit" name="form2-submit" value="form2" />
</form>
<form name="form3" action="filename.php" method="post">
....
<input type="submit" name="form3-submit" value="form3" />
</form>
```

filename.php

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['form1-submit'])) {
   //do something here;
}

if (!empty($_POST['form2-submit'])) {
   //do something here;
}
if (!empty($_POST['form3-submit'])) {
   //do something here;
}
?>
```

Comment: Well explained! I didn't know we could filter by hidden input[type="submit"]. This is definitely a more efficient way of compiling related functions into one php file rather than creating one php file for each. Thanks! I'm just starting to learn php form handling and this is very useful!

Comment: by *input[type="submit"]

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to have multiple forms in a page.

You could submit each to the same target script and differentiate by http method:

```
<form action="filename.php" method="post">
</form>
<form action="filename.php" method="get">
</form>
```

You could post to different targets:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
</form>
<form action="bar.php" method="get">
</form>
<form action="baz.php" method="post">
</form>
```

You could use a hidden value, and on the server script use that to differentiate between forms:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="foo">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="bar">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Example processing:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $form = isset($_POST['form'])
        ? $_POST['form']
        : null;

    switch($form) {
        case 'foo':
            process_form_foo($_POST);
        break;
        case 'bar':
            process_form_bar($_POST);
        break;
        default:
            throw new Exception('Invalid form submission.');
    } 

}
```

I'd be careful lumping all this together.  If you do, take care to break into manageable pieces.

Comment: Thanks @Progrock, I should probably be a bit more specific that I'm concerned with forms that use POST method. The different http method is a good suggestion though but I was also needing a bit of guidance as to how will the php file execute the right function for the correct form. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The different http method, was just an example of having more than one form on one page.  I've added a simple outline for multiple form processing.